# RestKit: How does one post an array of objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, restkit

**Question summary:**

Consider a class `SyncObject` that is KVC-compliant with properties such as: `time`, `someValue`, `lastChange`, `uuid`.

Consider an `NSArray` containing exclusively instances of `SyncObject`.

I need to submit the array to the server as a JSON array.

How would one submit this array to the server using HTTP POST using RestKit?

Example array:

```
[
  {
    "time": "14:45 10/21/2011",
    "someValue": "15",
    "lastChange": "14:45 10/21/2011",
    "uuid": "0b07c510-f4c8-11e0-be50-0800200c9a66"
  },
  {
    "time": "14:50 10/21/2011",
    "someValue": "62",
    "lastChange": "14:51 10/21/2011",
    "uuid": "1a6d4480-f4c8-11e0-be50-0800200c9a66"
  }
]
```

---

**Details**

I have an array of objects that I need to the server as JSON. It seems to me that RestKit is the easiest way to do this: I'm trying to avoid converting objects into a set of `NSDictionary` objects, and then using some JSON encoder to get JSON which I can `POST` to the server.

So, having created the array, and having set up the mapping for the class of objects stored in the array, I naturally try to `POST` to the server.

```
RKObjectManager* mgr = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://localhost/someweb/api/"];
mgr.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded;
mgr.client.username = @"username";
mgr.client.password = @"password";
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];
[mapping mapKeyPath: @"time"       toAttribute:@"time"         ];  
[mapping mapKeyPath: @"someValue"  toAttribute:@"someValue"    ];
[mapping mapKeyPath: @"lastChange" toAttribute:@"lastChange"   ];
[mapping mapKeyPath: @"uuid"       toAttribute:@"uuid"         ];
RKObjectMapping* mappingForSerialization = [mapping inverseMapping];
[mgr.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:mappingForSerialization 
                                    forClass:[NSManagedObject class]];

[mgr.router routeClass:[NSManagedObject class] toResourcePath:@"/sync" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];    

[mgr postObject:array delegate:nil/*self*/];
```

However, this is what I get out:

```
2011-10-11 14:57:51.769 AppConnect[1974:6e0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception '(null)', reason: 'Unable to find a routable path for object of type '__NSArrayI' for HTTP Method 'POST''
```

Apparently, RestKit does not know how to handle `NSArray`s.

**How does one post an array of objects using RestKit?**

---

I've tried something different: I replaced the last line with a manual send through `RKObjectLoader`.

```
//[mgr postObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:array forKey:@"data"] delegate:nil/*self*/];


NSString* syncPath = @"/sync"; 
RKObjectLoader * objectLoader = [mgr objectLoaderWithResourcePath:syncPath delegate:self];
objectLoader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
objectLoader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
//objectLoader.objectClass = [NSManagedObject class];       
//objectLoader.managedObjectStore = mgr.objectStore; 
objectLoader.params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:array 
                                                  forKey:@"MyData"]; 
[objectLoader send];
```

Unfortunately, this does not apply mapping of any sort, and instead transmits an array of objects' descriptions. Setting `serializationMIMEType` also does not affect the structure of transmitted contents, and `params` are always transmitted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I also tried assigning serialization mapping and passing the object as `targetObject` and `sourceObject` (this seems to be what RestKit does internally in `-[RKObjectManager postObject:delegate:]`).

```
RKObjectLoader * objectLoader = [mgr objectLoaderWithResourcePath:syncPath delegate:self];
objectLoader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
//objectLoader.objectClass = [NSManagedObject class];       
//objectLoader.managedObjectStore = mgr.objectStore; 
objectLoader.params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:array 
                                                  forKey:@"MyData"]; 
objectLoader.serializationMapping = mapping;
objectLoader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
objectLoader.sourceObject = objectLoader.params;
objectLoader.targetObject = objectLoader.params;
[objectLoader send];
```

Unfortunately, no mapping occurs this way:

```
2011-10-12 12:36:48.143 MyProject[5119:207] D restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:290 POST or PUT request for source object {
    MyData =     (
        "<NSManagedObject: 0x5935430> (entity: SomeRecord; id: 0x5934da0 <x-coredata://64DF9977-DA50-4FCD-8C20-4132E58439BF/SomeRecord/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
        "<NSManagedObject: 0x5935730> (entity: SomeRecord; id: 0x5934db0 <x-coredata://64DF9977-DA50-4FCD-8C20-4132E58439BF/SomeRecord/p2> ; data: <fault>)"
    );
}, serializing to MIME Type application/json for transport...
2011-10-12 12:36:48.143 MyProject[5119:207] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:428 Starting mapping operation...
2011-10-12 12:36:48.145 MyProject[5119:207] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:291 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'time'
2011-10-12 12:36:48.145 MyProject[5119:207] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:291 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'someValue'
2011-10-12 12:36:48.145 MyProject[5119:207] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:291 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'lastChange'
2011-10-12 12:36:48.145 MyProject[5119:207] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:291 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'uuid'
2011-10-12 12:36:48.145 MyProject[5119:207] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:448 Mapping operation did not find any mappable content
2011-10-12 12:36:48.146 MyProject[5119:207] T restkit.network:RKRequest.m:211 Prepared POST URLRequest '<NSMutableURLRequest http://someurl/api/sync?request=provide_key>'. HTTP Headers: {
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
}. HTTP Body: .
```

Comment: do you use CoreData in your project?

Comment: I do, but in case you were going to suggest it, I don't feel I need RestKit's CoreData integration in this case. Question currently stands as-is ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The restkit does not fund routable path for NSArray, because you defined your routing for `NSManagedObject` class. You probably want to create a custom class, say `MySyncEntity` that holds the ivars you define in your mapping. Then, you create your mapping like this:

```
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MySyncEntity class]];
....
[myManager setSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[[myManager router] routeClass:[MySyncEntity class] toResourcePath:@"/sync"];
```

then you should be able to post your object to the API backend as JSON object.

**Further clarification:**

In this case, we want to post an array of `NSManagedObject` instances into a JSON based API. To do that we need to create a sync entity, that holds the objects in an array:

```
@interface MySyncEntity : NSObject {}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* mySyncArray;
...
@end
```

The `mySyncArray` will hold the payload we'd like to submit to the rest backend. Then, we create appropriate mapping for both `NSManagedObject` that will be sent in `mySyncArray` and the `MySyncEntity` entity itself.

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:kBaseUrl];
...
RKObjectMapping *mngObjMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSManagedObject class]]; 
[mngObjMapping mapKeyPath: @"time" toAttribute:@"time"];  
[mngObjMapping mapKeyPath: @"recordLevel" toAttribute:@"recordLevel"];
.... //map as many properties as you wish
[[manager mappingProvider] setSerializationMapping:[mngObjMapping inverseMapping]
                                          forClass:[NSManagedObject class]];

//now, we create mapping for the MySyncEntity
RKObjectMapping *syncEntityMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MySyncEntity class]];
[syncEntityMapping mapKeyPath:@"mySyncArray" toRelationship:@"mySyncArray" withMapping:mngObjMapping];
[[manager mappingProvider] setSerializationMapping:[syncEntityMapping inverseMapping]
                                          forClass:[MySyncEntity class]];
```

Now with the mappings defined we can post the object to the server

```
[manager postObject:mySyncInstance delegate:nil];
```

The contents of `mySyncInstance` array will be mapped according to `mngObjMapping` and sent to defined rest endpoint.

Comment: So, I explicitly need to "contain" the `NSArray` as an i-var of a new object in order to submit the array to the server? Can't I, having defined the mapping for `NSMutableObject`s that are located in the array, just send the array directly?

Comment: i'm not sure it will work - i've always nested core datatypes under my 'wrapping' class because i transfer other data as well (not simple array). Either way, you mixed up a lot of different classes in your mapping - you defined a mapping for NSMutableDictionary where dictionary does not have any ivars like uuid and such, you set that mapping & define route for NSManagedObject and yet post an instance of NSArray. You have to stick to the same class through your definition

Comment: I guessed that `NSMutableDictionary` is the "reverse mapping" - that is, if I were downloading the data (which I'm currently not doing), I'd get it as dictionaries. Through KVC, it should Just Work™. Since I'm sending `NSManagedObject`s, I just defined mapping for them. Finally, I need to post an `NSArray` - and this is the actual thing that doesn't work.

Comment: will you try the approach i suggested in my answer? The idea of reverse mapping is that you may download the same entity as you need to push back into REST API. So, you define just one mapping (from API to entity) and then automagically create new serialization mapping based on your original (download) mapping.

Comment: As expected, this does nothing to help: RestKit still does not know how to map the `__NSArrayI` class. Details: I have implemented a new class `SyncBlob` which has a single readonly property `array`. I have defined a mapping for `SyncBlob` and its property.

Comment: what is the restkit log output for your SyncBlob attempt?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4195/discussion-between-mja-and-ivan-vucica)

Comment: thanks for resolving the issue in chat! i went through the whole thing and finally got what i needed. excellent.

Comment: I notice you give delegate:nil when post. What if I want to map the result back to managed objects? I tried that, and give me this error. Cannot map a collection of objects onto a non-mutable collection.

Comment: This solution also worked for me. I had to make some server adjustments as well, because the JSON that is being sent is not a list of enties anymore, but an object mySyncArray with an array of entities embedded in it.

Comment: The answers above are not relevant to Restkit 0.2.

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0

Answer (score 3):

As a further clarification, I'd like to point out that in [mja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726437/restkit-how-does-one-post-an-array-of-objects/7726829#7726829) the key thing is

```
[syncEntityMapping mapKeyPath:@"mySyncArray" toRelationship:@"mySyncArray" withMapping:mngObjMapping];
```

This says "the `mySyncArray` keypath is an array which contains objects that should be mapped according to `mngObjMapping`".