# Serializing a nested object when posting from iOS to Rails app

Tags: iphone, ios, serialization, restkit

Hoping to get a little push in the right direction.  I am having trouble getting a nested object to serialize properly when I POST to my rails app using RestKit.  I have the following mappings:

```
RKObjectMapping *cartSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[TOCart class]];
[cartSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"place.placeID" toAttribute:@"order[external_id]"];

//map the line items serialization mapping
RKObjectMapping *lineItemSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[TOLineItem class]];
[lineItemSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"itemID" toAttribute:@"itemID"];
[lineItemSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:lineItemSerializationMapping forClass:[TOLineItem class]];

//add relationship bw line items to TOLineItem
[cartSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"line_items" toRelationship:@"order[line_items]" withMapping:lineItemSerializationMapping serialize:YES];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:cartSerializationMapping forClass:[TOCart class]];
```

After posting to the server, serialization works for the parent object but not for the nested line_item object:

```
Started POST "/orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-16 04:05:58 -0800
Processing by OrdersController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"order"=>{"line_items"=>["<TOLineItem: 0x8aafdb0>"], "external_id"=>"4ae8a535f964a52024b121e3"}}
```

I want the line_item to serialize to itemID and name etc...

Did I set my mappings incorrectly?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

My TOCart class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class TOPlace;

@interface TOCart : NSObject
{
    NSNumber *cartID;
    TOPlace *place; //post to external id
    NSString *state;
    NSMutableArray *line_items;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *cartID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TOPlace *place;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *state;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *line_items;

@end
```

Comment: can you post your TOCart class? (ivars or property definitions)

Comment: Updated with my cart class.  Thx

Comment: I usually define my mapping to map from API to entities & then create serialization mapping using the inverseMapping selector. Take a look at my other answer as this may shed some light - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726437/restkit-how-does-one-post-an-array-of-objects/7726829#7726829

Comment: And you are awesome, that worked!  I wonder why we cant do serialization mappings by itself.  Can you post your link as an answer and I will accept it. thx again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always define my mapping to map from API to entities & then create the serialization mapping with  `[myMappingFromApi inverseMapping]` selector. You can find further details in my answer to somewhat different question, but definitely related: [RestKit: How does one post an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726437/restkit-how-does-one-post-an-array-of-objects/7726829#7726829).