# RestKit Arbitrary Keys Object Mapping

Tags: objective-c, mapping, restkit, object-object-mapping

I have a JSON that looks like this here:

```
 { 
  "key1":[ 
  { 
    "desc":"key1decs.", 
    "duration":50; 
  },{ 
    "desc":"", 
    "duration":90; 
  },{ 
    "desc":"Kurz vor...", 
    "duration":30; 
  } 
 ], 
 "key2":[ 
  { 
    "desc":"key2decs.", 
    "duration":50; 
  },{ 
    "desc":"blabla", 
    "duration":90; 
  } 
] 
}
```

I am trying to do a mapping. But I'm stuck because of different 
unknown/arbitrary keys. I tried mapping without KVC, but it seems not 
to be working. Gives me error: 
Failed transformation of value at keyPath 'key1.desc'. No strategy for 
transforming from '__NSArrayI' to 'NSString'. and so on for every 
attribute. 
I saw on the web that mapping without KVC doesn't support arrays as 
inner structures. Plz, help. What is right approach here?

EDIT: 
ENtity:

```
@interface Sendung : NSObject

 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *duration;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *sendungkey;
@end;
```

Controller:

```
 RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Sendung class]];
 mapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES;
[mapping mapKeyOfNestedDictionaryToAttribute:@"sendungkey"];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"(sendungkey).desc" toAttribute:@"description"];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"(sendungkey).duration" toAttribute:@"duration"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:mapping ];
 mapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Sendung class] ];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:url objectMapping:mapping delegate:self];
```

This is what I get when NSlogin result: (
    (null),
    (null),
    (null),
    (null),
    (null)
)

Comment: Yes, because your key1's content is an array. Can you please post your entities as well as the mapping definition?

Comment: i edited the question. thank you! I tried to do it with NSDictionary, but since I don't know keys it makes me very confused (

Comment: Can't use description as an attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you miss one 'level' of your mapping. If you take a closer look at your input, you have an dictionary (key1), which contents is not single '`Sendung`' but an array of such objects. Thus, you can't map contents of the key1 directly to `Sendung` ivars, rather than create new class, eg `SendungResult`.

```
@interface SendungResult : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *keyName;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *sendungs;
@end
```

and map the contents of key1 to `SendungResult` `sendungs` array using the relationship mapping you use now directly.

**EDIT:** I'm extending the answer as follows:

As i said earlier, you are trying to map a collection of objects into a single instance, so this can not work. Instead, you have to create a `SendungResult` that will hold an array of `Sendung` instances for one key. So in your example, you'll end up with two `SendungResult` instances (one will hold three `Sendung`s - those nested under `"key1"` and the second one just two, nested under `"key2"`). You can't map this kind of a structure into just once class, you have to nest them same way as your JSON is nested. The `Sendung` class is basically unchanged.

Now for the mapping. You need to define two mappings, one will map the contents of your root JSON into two `SendungResult` (one for each key) and the second mapping will map the inner part into individual `Sendung` instances.

We start with the inner mapping.

```
RKObjectMapping *sendungMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Sendung class]];
[sendungMapping mapKeyPath:@"desc" toAttribute:@"desc"];
[sendungMapping mapKeyPath:@"duration" toAttribute:@"duration"];
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] addObjectMapping:sendungMapping];
```

Nothing really interesting here, we just map the keypaths to your properties. Now for the outer part.

```
RKObjectMapping *resultMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SendungResult class]];
[resultMapping setForceCollectionMapping:YES];
[resultMapping mapKeyOfNestedDictionaryToAttribute:@"keyName"];
[resultMapping mapKeyPath:@"(keyName)" toRelationship:@"sendungs" withMapping:sendungMapping];
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] addObjectMapping:resultMapping];
```

We tell RestKit to map contents of the keyName keyPath to `sendungs` property found on `SendungResult` class with the mapping defined earlier.

Now we can fetch the data

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]  loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"test.js" objectMapping:resultMapping delegate:self];
```

The RestKit will create two `SendungResult` instances, each array contains the inner `Sendung` classes (3 and 2, respectively)

**Note:** I strongly suggest you to read [RestKit Object Mapping](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md) documentation. Also, JSONLint found your JSON to be invalid, i had to remove the semicolons. So be sure to use valid json.

Comment: i tried. here is the code:
     NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"/sendungen"] ;
    RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Sendung class]];

     [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
     @"desc", @"description",
     @"duration", @"duration",
     nil];

Comment: for(NSString *key in keys){
RKObjectMapping* generalMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[OIdClass class] ];

[generalMapping mapKeyPath:key toAttribute:@"senders"];

[generalMapping mapKeyPath:key toRelationship:key withMapping:mapping];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:generalMapping forKeyPath:key];
}    

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]  loadObjectsAtResourcePath:url delegate:self ];

As you see I have to iterate through my keys then to make each relationship :(
Result is with NO errors, but I get empty objects : ()

Comment: i don't quite follow why you have to iterate over you keys. Please refer to my another answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726437/restkit-how-does-one-post-an-array-of-objects/7726829#7726829 Note: that answer deals with posting an array of objets, but the same steps applies here, you just don't need to send the [mapping inverseMapping] selector.

Comment: forgive me my small knowledge of all this, but im very new to it. [syncEntityMapping mapKeyPath:@"mySyncArray" toRelationship:@"mySyncArray" withMapping:mngObjMapping];
What am I supposed to write for KeyPath ? I thought this is the key from JSon document. that is why i iterated over them.. am I wrong in my assumption? And I just thought maybe it is better if I can map it to dictionary? then all keys could be saved. Is there a way? Thanks a lot or an answers! I appreciate a lot!

Comment: about my valid json: i edited this by hand not to post my complicated example, so this might be my mistake.
I will get to my webservice at work next week, so I will be able to try it only then ( Thank you again!! I hope this save my place at work )) And I actually read documentation and have already done some mappings, but this one totally left me frustrated...

Comment: i posted you working solution, i.e. i tried to map your example with the mapping i posted, so you should be able to figure out the rest

Comment: Wow! awesome! It should be fine then i guess. +1 for you ;)

Comment: WOrked like charm! Cant believe i didn't come to this myself.. Thank you again!