# Implementing object mapping using RestKit in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, restkit

I am having trouble mapping a JSON response to objects using RestKit and Objective-C.

I have already set up my RKObjectManager and mappings in my AppDelegate as suggested in [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309543/mapping-a-json-response-to-an-object-using-restkit-and-objective-c) by [mja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/952753/mja).

I call my backend in my **controller** as per the example below.

There are two issues I'm having trouble with:

1. [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:request mapResponseWith:responseMapping delegate:self]; } <-- This results in a "self" is incompatible with type id. What do I need to send to this?
2. How do I cast the result in didLoadObject to the Translation object I've defined (translationText)

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
@synthesize inputtext = _text; 
@synthesize translation = _translation; 
@synthesize translatedText = _translatedText;

- (Translation *)translatedText {
if (!_translatedText) _translatedText = [[Translation alloc] init];
return _translatedText; }

- (IBAction)translatePressed {
//create TranslationRequest
TranslationRequest *request = [[TranslationRequest alloc] init];
[request setSourceId:@"1"];
[request setRegionTag:@"Hello"];
[request setInputString:self.inputtext.text];

//fetch the desired mapping to map response with
RKObjectMapping * responseMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Translation class]];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:request mapResponseWith:responseMapping delegate:self]; }

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObject:(id)object  { 
    self.translation.text = [object translatedText].translation; 
} 
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error { 
    NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to rectify the first issue, declare your controler in the .h file as follows:

```
#import "RestKit/RestKit.h"
...
@interface MyController : UIViewController<RKObjectLoaderDelegate>
```

You cast it just like this:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObject:(id)object  { 
    Translation *myTranslation = (Translation*)object;
    ... 
}
```

or you can avoid the cast by calling appropriate selector

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObject:(id)object  { 
    self.translation.text = [[object translatedText] translation];
}
```

you may update your question with the definition of @properties in your Translation object in order to be sure this answer is correct.

Comment: after re-reading your code i think you should do the following. Declare a retained property on yoyr controller and just assign the 'object' you get in your delegate to the property like this: self.translation = object; then you can access the values later in the class using the self.translation property (getter)