# How to prematurely cancel a request in RestKit and invoke 'didFailWithError'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, restkit

I am using **RestKit** in my Objective-C project and need to specify a timeout for a call to my service of around 10 seconds.

After reading around, it doesn't look like RestKit supports this, so my plan is to:

- Start a timer when my request is sent
- When the data is loaded, disable the timer

***Here's my problem...***

If the timer method fires, I need to cancel the request and invoke the method below manually. I'm not 100% sure how to achieve this.

There's some context in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319397/implementing-object-mapping-using-restkit-in-objective-c), showing how RestKit is implemented in my project and what it's doing in this case.

Many thanks in advance for any help you can give me on this one.

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error { 
     NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use cancelRequestsWithDelegate: selector in order to achieve the described workflow.

```
- (void)cancelAfterTimeout {
    [[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] client] requestQueue] cancelRequestsWithDelegate:self];
    NSError *myError = [[[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:NSPOSIXErrorDomain
            code:12345 userInfo:nil] autorelease];
    //feel free to customize the error code, domain and add userInfo when needed.
    [self handleRestKitError:myError];
}
```

However, it might be tricky to invoke that delegate error handler, but you can work around it by creating new, separate error handler like this:

```
- (void)handleRestKitError:(NSError*)error {
    //do something with the error
}
```

and modify the body of your `didFailWithError:` method:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error { 
     [self handleRestKitError:error] 
}
```

Comment: Thanks again mja. I'm getting Receiver type 'RKClient' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'requestQueue' when I add the first method to my controller. I assume the cancelAfterTimeout is the selected method for the timer firing?

Comment: I don't know why you would get that error. From looking at the sources i can see requestQueue property in the RKClient.h header (https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Code/Network/RKClient.h). Do you use recent version of RestKit? Yes, the cancelAfterTimeout is the selector to be send when timer fires.

Comment: I'm using 0.9 (from the version file)

Comment: do you use the version from GitHub? Can you check if your RKClient.h does have the requestQueue property defined?

Comment: The files are slightly different as I downloaded the latest build from the website about a week ago. I'll try updating.

Comment: i checked that the .zip version available on their homepage does not have this method implemented yet. I recommend you checking out the latest master branch. (here is very detailed guide as a reference https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x)

Comment: I just managed to check out my first items using git. The error has now disappeared. Now this method call is failing [self handleRestKitError:myError]; (does not declare a method with selector...) my method is declared as you suggested - (void)handleRestKitError:(NSError *)error {...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5512/discussion-between-nick-and-mja)

Comment: to 'fix' that one warning you need to declare your new selector in the header - just add - (void)handleRestKitError:(NSError*)error;  in your controller's .h file

Answer (score 8):

In RestKit version 0.20.x you can cancel scheduled requests using

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]
    cancelAllObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod:RKRequestMethodAny
                           matchingPathPattern:YOUR_PATTERN];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always end up with:

`[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].operationQueue cancelAllOperations];`

Each of your requests will finish with error *-999* (operation cancelled). You can check the *error.code* and perform appropriate action.