# Mapping nested objects with RestKit in Xcode using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, restkit

With the help of mja, I managed to successfully set up simple object mapping using RestKit and Objective-C. Please see my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309543/mapping-a-json-response-to-an-object-using-restkit-and-objective-c).

My next step was to attempt to deal with nested JSON in the same way.

My JSON looks like this, with the outer being a CandidatePhrase with some nested 'Votes':

```
{ "Id":33696,
"Phrase": "phrase",
"BadCount":0,
"Votes":[{"Id":447,"OriginalId":33696,"Votes":2,"Translation":"translation 1"},
{"Id":746,"OriginalId":33696,"Votes":1,"Translation":"translation 2"},
{"Id":747,"OriginalId":33696,"Votes":1,"Translation":"translation 3"}
]}
```

I created a relationship in my AppDelegate as follows:

```
[candidatePhraseMapping mapKeyPath:@"votes" toRelationship:@"vote" withMapping:voteMapping];
```

When I call make my request in my controller, I'm able to deal with the rest of the CandidatePhrase okay, but am not really sure how to map the nested 'Vote' objects into an array so I can use them in a TableView

(pseudo-code something like this...)

```
// Store the votes in an array
_votes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myCandidatePhrase.votes, nil];
```

**Here's my CandidatePhrase Object**

```
@interface CandidatePhrase : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* ident;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* badcount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* phrase;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* votes;

@end
```

**and my Vote object**

```
@interface Vote : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* ident;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* originalId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* votecount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* translation;

+ (id)voteWithTranslationId:(NSNumber *)ident translation:(NSString *)translation;

@end
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

## EDIT

Below is my mapping code

```
// Votes Mapping

RKObjectMapping* voteMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Vote class]];
[voteMapping mapKeyPath:@"Id" toAttribute:@"ident"];
[voteMapping mapKeyPath:@"OriginalId" toAttribute:@"originalId"];
[voteMapping mapKeyPath:@"Votes" toAttribute:@"votecount"];
[voteMapping mapKeyPath:@"Translation" toAttribute:@"translation"];

[[manager mappingProvider] addObjectMapping:voteMapping];

// Candidate Phrase Mapping
RKObjectMapping *candidatePhraseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CandidatePhrase class]];

[candidatePhraseMapping mapKeyPath:@"Id" toAttribute:@"ident"];
[candidatePhraseMapping mapKeyPath:@"Phrase" toAttribute:@"phrase"];
[candidatePhraseMapping mapKeyPath:@"BadCount" toAttribute:@"badcount"];

[candidatePhraseMapping mapKeyPath:@"Votes" toRelationship:@"votes" withMapping:voteMapping];

[[manager mappingProvider] addObjectMapping:candidatePhraseMapping];
```

For clarity also, here's how I'm attempting to access the vote items on the controller

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObject:(id)object 
{ 
    CandidatePhrase *myCandidatePhrase = (CandidatePhrase*)object;
    self.candidateText.text = myCandidatePhrase.phrase; <-- works fine

    _votes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myCandidatePhrase.votes, nil];
    for (id o2 in _votes) { 
        //Vote *vote = o2; 
        NSLog(@"Item name: %@", o2); <-- sees object but crashes
    }

    NSLog(@"Votes: %@", myCandidatePhrase.votes); 
    _votes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myCandidatePhrase.votes, nil];
     [_votesTableView reloadData];
 }
```

and my table is binding with

```
Vote *vote = [_votes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = vote.translation;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to manually manage the nested NSArray. I believe the problem might be just a simple typo, as you map keyPath "votes", but your json contain "Votes" with capital "V".

```
[candidatePhraseMapping mapKeyPath:@"Votes" toRelationship:@"votes" withMapping:voteMapping];
```

If this doesn't help feel free to leave a comment and update your question with `voteMapping`.

Also, the contents of the didLoadObject can be simplified:

```
//in .h file
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* votes;

// in implementation
@synthesize votes;

...
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObject:(id)object 
{ 
    CandidatePhrase *myCandidatePhrase = (CandidatePhrase*)object;
    self.candidateText.text = myCandidatePhrase.phrase;
    self.votes = myCandidatePhrase.votes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I updated my code above and am getting the error 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CandidatePhrase 0x821b5f0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key vote.'

Comment: I've also updated my code for accessing the vote property at the other end, if this helps.

Comment: Hi, i think this line is the problem... _votes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myCandidatePhrase.votes, nil]; the myCandidatePhrase.votes is an array by itself. Do you want to have an array that has just one object - being an array of votes?

Comment: reading your last edit, apparently not. Why not just keep the whole (CandidatePhrase*)object; in a property? What type is the self.candidateText property?

Comment: This is NSString. CandidatePhrase is the outer object, and can have multiple votes associated with it.

Comment: Apologies. CandidateText is just a label for output

Comment: Ah i see. Okay then, define a new property of type NSArray (e.g. @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* votes; and assign the votes to your new property like this: self.votes = myCandidatePhrase.votes; (keep lines 1&2, add the self.votes assignment and remove the rest of the delegate callback contents)

Comment: Typical. I think I was trying to over-complicate things. This works spot on. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I also updated my answer with the hint from my comment.