# RestKit after post json, how to map json response to objects

Tags: restkit

I follow this link https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Posting-NSDictionary-as-JSON to create the json post, and get back json response from server. How could I continue process the json response to a list of objects?

```
- (void)sendAsJSON:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {

    RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:@"http://restkit.org"];        

    // create a JSON string from your NSDictionary 
    id<RKParser> parser = [[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] parserForMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *json = [parser stringFromObject:dictionary error:&error];

    // send your data
    if (!error)
        [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/some/path" params:[RKRequestSerialization serializationWithData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON] delegate:self];

}


- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"after posting to server, %@", [response bodyAsString]);
}
```

**EDIT1:** this is the Json I want to POST to server.

```
{
    "memberId": "1000000",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "phoneNumber": "+12233333333",
            "memberId": "2222",
            "contactId": "123456",
            "name": "john"
        },
        {
            "phoneNumber": "+12244444444",
            "memberId": "3333",
            "contactId": "123457",
            "name": "mary"
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT2:** Someone actually resolved this in another thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7726829/772481

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use RKObjectManger instead of RKClient to do the POST.  You can then load the response into objects when this method is called:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects
```

**EDIT (given JSON to send to server):**

Instead of creating the JSON the way that you're currently doing it, you can create custom model classes.

First, you can create a model class for your top level object (assuming it's called User).

*User Header*

```
//  User.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface User : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int memberId;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *countryCode;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *contacts;

@end
```

*User Implementation*

```
//  User.m

#import "User.h"

@implementation User

@synthesize memberId;
@synthesize countryCode;
@synthesize contacts;

@end
```

Then, you can create a model class called Contact.

*Contact Header*

```
//  Contact.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Contact : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *phoneNumber;
@property (nonatomic) int memberId;
@property (nonatomic) int contactId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end
```

*Contact Implementation*

```
//  Contact.m

#import "Contact.h"

@implementation Contact

@synthesize phoneNumber;
@synthesize memberId;
@synthesize contactId;
@synthesize name;

@end
```

You can use these classes as so:

```
Contact *john = [[Contact alloc] init];
john.phoneNumber = @"+12233333333";
john.memberId = 2222;
john.contactId = 123456;
john.name = @"john";

Contact *mary = [[Contact alloc] init];
mary.phoneNumber = @"+12244444444";
mary.memberId = 3333;
mary.contactId = 123457;
mary.name = @"mary";

User *user = [[User alloc] init];
user.memberId = 1000000;
user.countryCode = @"US";
user.contacts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:john, mary, nil];

RKObjectMapping *contactsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Contact class]];
[contactsMapping mapKeyPath:@"phoneNumber" toAttribute:@"phoneNumber"];
[contactsMapping mapKeyPath:@"memberId" toAttribute:@"memberId"];
[contactsMapping mapKeyPath:@"contactId" toAttribute:@"contactId"];
[contactsMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];

RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];
[objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"memberId" toAttribute:@"memberId"];
[objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"countryCode" toAttribute:@"countryCode"];
[objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"contacts" toRelationship:@"contacts" withMapping:contactsMapping];

//Then you set up a serialization mapping and object mapping and POST it

//This method takes care of both the serialization and object mapping
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider registerMapping:objectMapping withRootKeyPath:@"user"]; 

//POST it
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:user delegate:self];
```

I would need to know what kind of JSON response you're expecting before I can show you how to do the serialization mapping and the POST.

**EDIT (given JSON returned from server)**:

To set the serialization mapping and object mapping and POST it, you'll need to set up the resource path (I do it when I launch my app):

```
RKObjectRouter *router = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].router;
[router routeClass:[User class] toResourcePath:@"/users" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

Your resource path may be something other than "/users".

Take a look at the code under the comment `//Then you set up a serialization mapping and object mapping and POST it`, where I have added the serialization mapping, object mapping, and POSTing.

Comment: Does RKObjectManger allow me to POST a Json body?

Comment: Yep.  You should set up an object mapping to turn your objects into JSON.  Do you know how to do that?  If you don't, give me an example of an object that you want to POST, and I'll show you how.

Comment: I put the json under my question. The Json is created programmatically.

Comment: See the updated answer.  What is the JSON that you're expecting the server to return?

Comment: Basically the same JSON string. This POST is used to filter contacts. Say, the POST contains 5 contacts and it might return 3 contacts. I want these 3 contacts to save in core data. I already have class for contact, however, it is NSManagedObject.

Comment: I added some code above.  I haven't used it with CoreData myself, so unfortunately I can't provide any help there (yet).

Comment: Could you please explain a little further about where to put the RKObjectRouter code? For the POST, does it post as FormUrlEncoded or Json body? Would it post a list of contacts or just a single row?

Comment: I just found the solution from another thread which basically discusses on same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7726829/772481

Answer (score 0):

Normally in this situation you would use `RKObjectLoader`, which can be accessed through `RKObjectManager` as @ill_always_be_a_warriors said. The reason you use this is because it includes free object mapping if configured. One thing to note is you post an 'object' and not JSON directly. For more info try looking at the [RestKit examples](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/tree/master/Examples) to see how to do this, THEN if you still have problems post a question here.