# Request Mapping in RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit Only introduced mapping of JSON :

```
{
    a : "a",
    b : "b"
}
```

Mapping with Objective-C code:

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"entityId" : @"id"}];
```

But it do not show me how to mapping JSON Like:

```
{
    entity: {
        id: "xxxxxxxxx",
        model : {
            a : "a",
            b : "b"           
        }
    }
}
```

I did some attempt,
I create two model class like:

```
@interface Entity : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *entityId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject *model;
@end
```

and

```
@interface Model : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *a;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *b;
@end
```

I make some RelationShipMapping Like ReponseMapping

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"entityId" : @"id"}];
RKObjectMapping *modelMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[modelMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"a" : @"b"}];
RKRelationshipMapping *modelToEntityMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"model" toKeyPath:@"model" withMapping:modelMapping];
[requestMapping addPropertyMapping:modelToEntityMapping];
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[Entity class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
```

the following code I create the object

```
Entity *entity = [Entity new];
entity.entityId = @"/example/entityId";
Model *exampleModel = [ExampleModel new];
exampleModel.a = @"a";
exampleModel.b = @"b";
entity.model = exampleModel;
```

But I log the post JSON on my server:

```
{ id: '/example/entityId', 'model[a]': 'a', 'model[b]': 'b' }
```

So how to make a relationship when use requestMapping？

Comment: change this [modelMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"a" : @"a",
                                                                               @"b" : @"b"}];

Comment: Did you set the request serialisation to JSON?

Comment: Did you got a solution for the problem? I'm facing the same thing.

Comment: I just found that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726437/restkit-how-does-one-post-an-array-of-objects and worked for me just adding the request serialization [objectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];